# Validation | required="true" / "false" | HTML form

Tags: html, forms, attributes

While I was doing some basic HTML I was wondering why Sublime Text 3 always completes `required`  into `required=""` . Like my Instructor in an online course said it is not necessary to set `required="true"`  or `required="false"`  but when I set it to false it still requires it.

example code (it will require the field even if it is set tofalse):

```html
<form>
    <input type="password" name="password" required="false">
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

---

I hope you can clear up the confusion. Thanks for every answer.

Farcher

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to not require a required input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615768/how-to-not-require-a-required-input)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In HTML, the [required](http://w3c.github.io/html/sec-forms.html#the-required-attribute) attribute must be **present** (the field is required) or absent (the field is *NOT* required). When the attribute is present, it does not matter what *value* it has.

> The required attribute is a boolean attribute. When specified, the element is required.
>
> The presence of a boolean attribute on an element represents the true value, and the absence of the attribute represents the false value.

About [boolean attributes](http://w3c.github.io/html/infrastructure.html#boolean-attribute):

> A boolean attribute without a value assigned to it (e.g. checked) is implicitly equivalent to one that has the empty string assigned to it (i.e. checked=""). As a consequence, it represents the true value.
>
> The values "true" and "false" are not allowed on boolean attributes. To represent a false value, the attribute has to be omitted altogether.

A common practice is to use the *name* of the attribute as its *value*:

```
<form>
    <input type="password" name="password" required="required"><!-- this input is required -->

    <input type="text" name="sometext"><!-- this input is NOT required -->

    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Beautiful answer, this is exactly the data I needed to figure out why my input in Vue JS was always showing `required="required"` in the DOM. It was actually showing that regardless of what I passed. The prop was either omitted or `required="required"`. I think Vue may do some processing under the hood to constrain it to `required="required"`.

Answer (score 1):

`required` doesn't take a boolean string. It's required if the attribute exists at all. Sublime is likely expecting some value like most attributes.

```html
<form>
<input type="password" name="password" required="">
<button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

```html
<form>
<input type="password" name="password" required>
<button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

'Required' is a Boolean attribute. It assumes the value of true once it is present. therefore setting it to a 'false' still makes it act as though it was true.

Below is proof

```
<form>
<input type="password" name="password" required="false">
<button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

However,  if one is handling mouse events, for instance, using JS, they can set the "required" attribute to "True" or "False" using the ".prop()" method. e.g.

```
.prop("required", true)
```

OR

```
.prop("required", false)
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect and may be jQuery specific. There in no .prop() method in JavaScript.